# Condicionar Autoejecución de eventos (métodos) de un componente web con LitElement y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy trabajando en un componente Select con LitElement y JavaScript, el componente tiene eventos personalizados como por ejemplo un 'Change', el detalle que tengo es que, al cargar la pagina(o recargarla), en automático se ejecuta este evento y por consiguiente su método, sin antes seleccionar alguno de los items del Select.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
selectOptionAllinversiones(e) { 
  console.log('entre en evento del select');
  this.selectAllinversionCheques = e.target.value; 
  this.selectIndex = e.target.selectedIndex; 
}
```

```html
 <web-form-select @change="${this.selectOptionAllinversiones}" id="selectAllinversiones" label="Seleccionar cuenta de cheques o alias">
  ${this._lstSelectCuentaAllinversiones}
</web-form-select>
```

Comment: Muestra un [repro]: lee [ask].

Comment: //HTML
<web-form-select @change="${this.selectOptionAllinversiones}" id="selectAllinversiones" label="Seleccionar cuenta de cheques o alias">${this._lstSelectCuentaAllinversiones}</web-form-select>
//JavaScript
selectOptionAllinversiones(e) {
    this.selectAllinversionCheques = e.target.value;
    this.selectIndex = e.target.selectedIndex;
  }
Tengo este componente select, y dentro del select tengo otro componente para los items del select, cuando, cargo la pagina se autoejecuta el evento del select, sin que seleccione ningún item

Comment: Como te habrás dado cuenta, el código es ilegible en un comentario. Debes [edit] tu pregunta (y darle el formato correspondiente al código).